# WPF designer instantiating object and causing compiler error

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have solution called **MySol**.

I have a DLL project in **MySol** called **DeviceProj**. This project defines a class:

```
public class Device
{
    public int NumFields { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a WPF UserControl project in **MySol** called **DeviceControl**. This class looks something like this:

```
public class DeviceControl : UserControl
{
    private Device _MyDevice;

    public Device MyDevice 
    {
        get { return _MyDevice; }
        set
        {
            _MyDevice = value;
            for (var i = 0; i < _MyDevice.NumFields; i++)
                Main.Children.Add(new TextBox());
        }
    }

    public DeviceControl()
    {
        MyDevice = new Device { NumFields = 4 };

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a WPF Application project in **MySol** called **DeviceWindow**. When I add a **DeviceControl** to the **DeviceWindow** Designer, I see my control with 4 text boxes (this is expected: the designer creates an instance of **DeviceControl** and, since the default **Device** has its **NumFields** property set to 4, there are 4 text boxes).

But, when I compile **MySol**, I get the error:

*Error  1   Unable to copy file "C:\path\to\Device.dll" to "bin\Debug\Device.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Device.dll' because it is being used by another process.*

I assume this is because an instance of **Device** is being used by the WPF designer, so the DLL cannot be overwritten.

Is there any way around this problem?

**Shorter, easier to understand (maybe?) explanation:**

The WPF Window designer creates an instance of all UserControls declared in the window. If one of those UserControls contains a reference to an object declared in a different project (we'll call it **ObjectProject**) in the same solution, the solution will not build because the **ObjectProject** .dll will be in use by the WPF designer. Visual Studio cannot overwrite .dll files that are in use.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your solution? Closing and reopening Visual Studio? Rebooting the machine?

Comment: Yes, I've tried all those things. I think I know WHY it is happening (the DLL is indeed in use by the WPF designer), I just want to know how to change the behavior of the designer or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue is your .DLL and your WPF application targets may differ. Your application target may be Client Profile.
Keep both the target to same.

For example, if your library targets .NET 4, make sure your WPF Application targets also 4, not client profile.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\path\to\Device.dll` and `bin\Debug\Device.dll` folder of your project then delete the `Device.dll` file from these two locations. When you run your project again, these files will be created automatically in the directory. Then you can build without this error.